# Working with operators from string in JS without 'eval()' or 'new Function()'

Tags: javascript, string, operators

I got an assignment where a DB has operator conditions (`===`, `<`, `>`, `*` etc) to use with some accompanying data.

I need to run those conditions in my JavaScript code.
What I found around here is usage of `eval` or the `Function` constructor,
but both have crucial security and performance issues and are not an option for production code in any sense.

Example:

`const operatorFromDB = '>'`

`const param1FromDB = '10'`

`const param2FromDB = '5'`

But running `eval('${param1FromDB}${operatorFromDB}${param2FromDB}')` is problematic.

So, how do I actually solve this?

Comment: can you give more context

Comment: @Teemu added an example in the post.

Comment: @cmgchess added an example. please let me know if you need anything more

Comment: how about using logic like if operator is '>' do param1 > param2 and so on. i meant switch statement or if else

Comment: A popular way is to create an object with operator methods, like `ops = {'>': (a, b) => a > b}`, then call ex. `ops['>'](3, 2)`.